# How to force using GET instead of POST

Tags: post, get

Is it possible to force a page to use GET method (so i can pass the request in the address line using JS), when it is using POST?

*NOTE*: I do not have access to source code and not able to edit anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, It is not possible to force a page to use GET method instead of POST.

Because It is always based on the server side program ,like what type of method it will accept either GET or POST or both.so you can force any thing from front end.